# When you create a ss public key, does it create a private key as well as a pair?

Tags: ssh, vpn

I currently only have a public key. Not sure if it created a private key as well?

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'streisand_ssh_private_key' is undefined"}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ssh-keygen -t rsa` command it creates a pair of public and private key.

In `~/.ssh` directory you should find this keypair in files `rsa_id` and `rsa_id.pub`.